# Json data - Undefined

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-5

I try to get Json result from a Controller Action.

In my view a have an Ajax.ActionLink

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Aggiungi riga", "Step2", new AjaxOptions { Url = Url.Action("RitornaRigheJson"), OnSuccess = "processData" })
```

Into controller I have

```
public JsonResult RitornaRigheJson()
{
    RigaFattura data = new RigaFattura();
    data.Descrizione = "Json";
    data.nriga = 1;
    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

that produce a json object . I test the Action RitornaRigheJson and see the correct output.

Now the problem is OnSuccess = "processData". Into View I have a javascript class

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function processData(data)
  {
    alert(data)
    var a = data[0];
    alert(a);
  }
</script>
```

but the value of data is always "undefined"

Comment: `console.log(data);`

Comment: The object is undefined. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved.
The problem is the controller. I change it into

```
public JsonResult RitornaRigheJson()
    {
    RigaFattura[] elenco = {new RigaFattura{nriga = 1,Descrizione="Prova Riga"}};
    IEnumerable<RigaFattura> data = elenco;                       
    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```